# My windows phone keyboard is getting smaller, what should I do to make it back to original size

Tags: windows-10-mobile, settings, keyboard

Why my windows 10 phone keyboard changed smaller, I do not know why,
I have tried to change the keyboard size setting to large, but there is no effect (still small). what should I do to make it back to original size.

My keyboard before update
[image]

After update
[image]

I have tried to change the keyboard size setting to large, but there is no effect. (still small).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long press on &123 until three buttons slide up. Press on keyboard icon then full setup for the keyboard as demonstrated in this picture.[image]

Comment: Tq, I press the language button (not &123 button), and the keyboard setting come out, after click the large keyboard button, it back to original size

Answer (score 1):

OK, thanks, after fiddling some time with the advices above, the -> Settings -> Time and language -> Keyboard -> More settings -> Keyboard size, did suddenly get functioning, great!

And as noted above, on my Lumia 640XL case, the quick fine-tuning key when writing is the language key instead of the &123.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to return it back is just to **long press on the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> key** and move to the opposite of the side which the small keyboard is, that is, towards the middle.

For the record, the keyboard goes to that mode when you long press on the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> key, and drag your finger to the left or right, then releasing. Its actually a feature that enables you to use a Windows 10 Mobile keyboard with a single hand. So I guess you were activating it accidentally by pressing on the space key and squishing the keyboard to either the left or right of the phone’s display.

[image]

Also, you can move the keyboard from the bottom of the screen to any point convenient to your liking.